# Alamofire 4 URL Request parameter encoding to JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Recently upgraded to Alamofire 4 and running into few issues. Wondering how to encode the url request parameter to JSON in Alamofire Router. Here is the example I was following in Alamofire 3.

```
enum UserRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
  static let baseURLString = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"

  case Get(Int)
  case Create([String: AnyObject])
  case Delete(Int)

  var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
    var method: Alamofire.Method {
      switch self {
      case .Get:
        return .GET
      case .Create:
        return .POST

      }
    }

    let params: ([String: AnyObject]?) = {
      switch self {
      case .Get:
        return (nil)
      case .Create(let newPost):
        return (newPost)
      }
    }()

    let url:NSURL = {
      let relativePath:String?
      switch self {
      case .Get(let postNumber):
        relativePath = "posts/\(postNumber)"
      case .Create:
        relativePath = "posts"
      }

      var URL = NSURL(string: PostRouter.baseURLString)!
      if let relativePath = relativePath {
        URL = URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(relativePath)
      }
      return URL
    }()

    let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
    let (encodedRequest, _) = encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: params)

    encodedRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

    return encodedRequest
  }
}
```

It seems now in Alamofire 4 this has been changed.

```
let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
let (encodedRequest, _) = encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: params)
```

Here is what I am trying with Alamofire 4 Router, but not working as expected.

```
func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = try UserRouter.baseURLString.asURL()

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue


        switch self {
            case .updateDeviceToken(_,let device):
                urlRequest =  try ParameterEncoding.encode(urlRequest as URLRequestConvertible, with: device)
                //urlRequest = try  JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: device)
            case .addUser(_, let user):
                urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: user)
            case .updateUser(_,_,let user):
                urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: user)
            case .lockUser(_,_,let user):
                urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: user)
            default:
                break
        }
        return urlRequest
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I use this encoding syntax:

```
...
method: .get,
parameters: parameters,
encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
headers: nil,
...
```

In your case, it could be like this:

```
let encoding = Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default
```

I was struggling with this issue too, until I found a simple example here:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#json-encoding

Comment: Actually I tried that, but didn't paid attention to the error I was getting in xcode. It seems my device dictionary object was badly formed due to nil in the notificationToken key.   ["notificationToken": optional(nil), "deviceId": "6f61f29e-c01b-4010-b587-74b2a0bdf96b"]